# Mi programa ignora los eventos de teclado de un JPanel tras haber superpuesto otro distinto

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy intentando programar un juego que se compone de un frame y dos paneles (Partida y GameOver).

El primer panel es en el que el juego se desarrolla (es el JPanel en el que se dibujan los componentes del juego y donde el usuario interacciona con los mismos mediante un KeyListener) y el segundo es la pantalla de game over, en la que hay dos JButtons (uno para salir del juego con un System.exit y otro para iniciar otra nueva partida, es decir, restablecer los parámetros por defecto del primer JPanel).

Durante la ejecución del programa, la primera partida es automática y el frame sólo tiene un sólo JPanel (el de la partida) y cuando el usuario pierde, se añade encima la de game over. Hasta ahí bien, pero el problema se da cuando se inicia otra partida (la visibilidad del segundo JPanel se establece en false) ya que el JPanel partida ahora no responde ante los eventos que antes si.

He estado haciendo pruebas y he descubierto que al iniciar otra partida, no se activa ni el método KeyPressed ni KeyReleased del oyente.

La clase Partida:

```
     import java.awt.*;
     import java.awt.event*;
     import javax.swing.*;

 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class Partida extends JPanel {

    GameOverPanel gameOver;
    private Ball ball;
    private Racket racket;
    boolean stop;
    int stopGame;
    boolean toReset;

    public Partida() {

        gameOver = new GameOverPanel(this);
        gameOver.aceptButton.addActionListener(new oyente());
        gameOver.replayButton.addActionListener(new oyente());

        stop = false;
        ball = new Ball(this);
        racket = new Racket(this);

        addKeyListener(new oyenteTeclado());
        setFocusable(true);

        stopGame = 0;
        toReset = false;
    }

    public Racket getRacket() {
        return this.racket;
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.stop = true;
    }

    public void move() {
        if (stop == false) {
            this.ball.move();
            this.racket.move();
        }
    }

    private class oyenteTeclado implements KeyListener {

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            racket.keyPressed(e);
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            racket.keyReleased(e);
        }

    }

    private class ActListOyt implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
                menu.actionPerformed(e);
        }   
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g); 
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ball.paint(g2);
        racket.paint(g2);
    }

    public void gameOver() {
        this.stopGame = 1;
    }

    public void resetValues() {
        this.stop = false;
        this.stopGame = 0;
        this.toReset = false;
        this.ball.setDefault();
        this.racket.setDefault();
        }
}
```

La clase GameOver:

```
      import java.awt.*;
      import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
      import javax.swing.*;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class GameOverPanel extends JPanel {

    private String txt1 = "GAME OVER";
    JButton aceptButton;
    JButton replayButton;
    private Partida partida;

    public GameOverPanel(Partida partida) {

        setVisible(false);

        setLayout(null);

        aceptButton = new JButton("CLOSE");
        aceptButton.setBounds(95, 170, 100, 50);

        replayButton = new JButton("PLAY AGAIN");
        replayButton.setBounds(70, 230, 150, 50);

        add(aceptButton);
        add(replayButton);

        this.partida = partida;
        game.stop();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.drawString(txt1, 60, 100);
        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String input = e.getActionCommand();
        if(input.equals("CLOSE")) {
            System.exit(ABORT);
        }
        else if(input.equals("PLAY AGAIN")) {
            game.toReset = true;
        }

        }
    }
```

El método main es el siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        Toolkit scr = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension sz = scr.getScreenSize();

        Partida partida = new Partida();
        JFrame Frame = new JFrame("Juego");

        partida.menu.setVisible(false);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocation(sz.width/4, sz.height/3);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        while (true) {

            relaxMusic.start();
            game.move();
            game.repaint(); 
            Thread.sleep(10);

            if (game.stopGame == 1) {

                game.setVisible(false);
                frame.add(game.menu);
                game.menu.setVisible(true);

                if (game.toReset == true) {

                    game.resetValues();
                    game.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Posiblemente requiera recargar el panel de la partida.

Comment: @Alfabravo Si es así, ¿Como recargo un JPanel?

Comment: Suele ser con `repaint()` y `revalidate()`.